# Understanding map function

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be the closest equivalent to the `map` function in python? For example:

```
def my_map(func, arg_list):
    return [func(arg) for arg in arg_list]

def my_squared_func(arg):
    return arg * arg

my_map(func=squared, arg_list=[1,2,3,4,5])
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Is this approximately what `map()` returns, if not, what does the function look like?

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: Yes.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: @JosephSible it doesn't seem that way though? It seems `map` passed back a generator instead of just a list?

Comment: "Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results." see docs in link above

Comment: @FI-Info You did say "approximately" in your question. The generator and the list will have the same elements in the same order, and in most cases, Python lets you use them interchangeably.